# Quartic Formulation of tan(x) = x

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, quartics

I want to convert the above equation into quartic form. The only thing I can think of is to use the Taylor series expansion of tan(x). Is there any other way, anyone can suggest to convert the above equation into quartic form.

Comment: Why do you think it can be cast into quartic form?

Comment: When solving something like
$$
\tan x = x
$$
it's best to graph $f(x)=\tan x$ and $g(x)=x$. You'll see that if you have only one branch of the tangent function, the only solution is the trivial $x=0$. The other solutions are in the other branches. For this reason, a polynomial approximation of $\tan x$, which will only produce one branch, would yield no further information on the matter.

Comment: @MattiP. Thank you for the suggestion! I'll graph it to see the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the roots of the equation $\tan(x)=x$, as said in comments, there is an inifinite number of solutions closer and closer to $(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$.

Consider instead that you look for the zero's of
$$f(x)=\sin(x)-x \cos(x)$$ and develop as series around $\color{blue}{x_{(n)}=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2}$.
$$f(x)=1+x_{(n)} (x-x_{(n)})+\frac{1}{2} (x-x_{(n)})^2-\frac{1}{6} x_{(n)} (x-x_{(n)})^3-\frac{1}{8}
   (x-x_{(n)})^4+O\left((x-x_{(n)})^{5}\right)$$

Using it for $n=4$ and solving the quartic would give as an approximate solution $14.0661939128333$ while the exact solution, obtained using Newton method, is $14.0661939128315$.

Going one step further, you could even use series reversion to get
$$x_n=x_{(n)}-\frac{1}{x_{(n)}}-\frac{2}{3 x_{(n)}^3}-\frac{19}{24 x_{(n)}^5}-\frac{5}{8
   x_{(n)}^7}+O\left(\frac{1}{x_{(n)}^9}\right)$$ Applied to the case where $n=4$, this would give $x_4=14.06619405$

Comment: Newton's method does not give an exact answer. The answer you give is still an approximation (which is exact to 15 decimals).

Comment: @BernardMassé. What else could I say beside *I fully agree with you*. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Very much appreciate your answer!

Comment: @BernardMassé I'm trying to compare Newton's method and quartic method, so approximate solution works just fine in this case.